# ASP.NET Core 6 gRPC when communicate client and server - getting Grpc.Core.RpcException

Tags: c#, microservices, grpc, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a C# program using gRPC to communicate between the client service, which is `Basket.Api`, and the server service, which is `Discount.gRPC`. I get an error

> Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unknown", Detail="Exception was thrown by handler.")

when calling the `GetDiscount` function from the service client.

The stack trace is:

```
at Basket.Api.Services.DiscountGrpc.DiscountClientService.GetDiscount(String productName) in E:\Microservices\run-aspnetcore-microservices\EcommerceMicro\Basket.Api\Services\DiscountGrpc\DiscountClientService.cs:line 17  
at Basket.Api.Controllers.BasketController.UpdateBasket(ShoppingCart basket) in E:\Microservices\run-aspnetcore-microservices\EcommerceMicro\Basket.Api\Controllers\BasketController.cs:line 39  
at lambda_method23(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Here is image for solution folder structure `Discount.gRPC` and `Basket.Api`:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1wCT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmRbF.png)

The `GetDiscount` method in the proto file is as follows:

```
option csharp_namespace = "Discount.gRPC.Protos";

service DiscountProtoService {
    rpc GetDiscount(GetDiscountRequest) returns (CouponModel);
}

message GetDiscountRequest {
    string productName = 1;
}

message CouponModel {
    int32 id = 1;
    string productId=2;
    string productName = 3;
    string description = 4;
    int32 amount = 5;
}
```

The `GetDiscount` implementation in Client:

```
private readonly DiscountProtoService.DiscountProtoServiceClient discountClientService;

public DiscountClientService(DiscountProtoService.DiscountProtoServiceClient discountClientService)
{
    this.discountClientService = discountClientService;
}

public async Task<CouponModel> GetDiscount(string productName)
{
    var discountRequest = new GetDiscountRequest { ProductName = productName };
    return await discountClientService.GetDiscountAsync(discountRequest);
}
```

I registered the services for client-side in `Program.cs` of the ASP.NET Core 6 Web API:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddScoped<IGreeterClientService, GreeterClientService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDiscountClientService, DiscountClientService>();
builder.Services.AddGrpcClient<Greeter.GreeterClient>(c => c.Address = new Uri(builder.Configuration["GrpcSettings:DiscountUrl"]));
builder.Services.AddGrpcClient<DiscountProtoService.DiscountProtoServiceClient>(c => c.Address = new Uri(builder.Configuration["GrpcSettings:DiscountUrl"]));
var app = builder.Build();
```

The server-side implementation of the method:

```
public override async Task<CouponModel> GetDiscount(GetDiscountRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
{
    var coupon = await repository.GetDiscount(request.ProductName);

    if (coupon == null)
    {
        throw new RpcException(new Status(StatusCode.NotFound, $"Discount with ProductName = {request.ProductName} not found."));
    }

    var couponModel = mapper.Map<CouponModel>(coupon);

    logger.LogInformation("Discount is retrieved for ProductName : {productName}, Amount : {amount}", request.ProductName, coupon.Amount);

    return await Task.FromResult(couponModel);
    //return await Task.FromResult(new CouponModel());
}
```

I registered services for server-side in `Program.cs` in `Discount.gRPC` project:

```
using Discount.gRPC.Mapper;
using Discount.gRPC.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddGrpc();
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(DiscountProfile));
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();
app.MapGrpcService<DiscountService>();

app.Run();
```

I have tested the communication between the client-side and server-side using the greeter (default service of ASP.NET Core gRPC Service) in my Discount.gRPC, and it is working fine.

I hope that someone can point out any errors in my code or configuration. I am willing to provide additional code to facilitate identifying the issue and finding a solution.

Comment: Did you run it in a debugger to see what exception happens on line 17 of your code?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen yes, I used debugger and get the same error message is "Status(StatusCode="Unknown", Detail="Exception was thrown by handler.")"